# Avoiding server timeout in long running POST request

Tags: python, post, solr, timeout

I'm sending POST request using python [requests](http://www.python-requests.org/) library and reading data from an iterator.

If the iterator yields data quickly all works perfectly.

The problem is that my iterator sometimes "takes a break", the server disconnects due to inactivity and my client raises a `Broken pipe` exception at socket level. I can't avoid pauses on source iterator because they depends on  computation time.

The server is SOLR, but I think this should be a more general question.

To be more precise the situation is like this (I'm simplifying because original code is quite complex):

```
import requests
def myObjectsIter():
    #this generator yields custom objects and sometimes pauses

def myObjectsSerializerIter():
    yield "<add>"
    for o in myObjectsIter():
        #o.serialize returns an XML string for SOLR update (<doc>...</doc>)
        yield o.serialize()
    yield "</add>"

requests.post("http://mysolr/mycore/update", data=myObjectsSerializerIter())

#When myObjectsIter pauses for more than (i think) 60 seconds the last call raises [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Does anyone know any good practice to avoid such a situation?

Comment: after success, success, on error ? can't see any one condition.Set a server response is "OK" message. you don't care about the server status ?

Comment: @dsgdfg. Sorry but I don't understand your comment. Is there something unclear in my question?

Comment: How do you make sure that the server has received the package? Where's your feedback message? Many service is restricted for the duration of the request.

Comment: @dsgdfg The server does not actually receive all the data because when the client pauses for more than (i think) 60 seconds it closes the socket on its side and the client raises a Broken pipe exception. This is quite clear to me. My question is about ways to avoid this.
I updated the question to be clearer.

Comment: here : http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.exceptions.Timeout  But you try to clone a web service(maybe, only my idea) how to handle session ? Use selenium etc. dont waste your time... @zac